# AEM Dispatcher - cache rules

Tags: caching, aem

I am looking to get an understanding on a part of AEM dispatcher configuration. This will go under /cache /rules section

It looks like something below

```
/rules
        {
        # initial blanket deny
          /0000
          {
            /glob "*"
            /type "deny"
          }
          /0100
          {
           /glob "*.html"
           /type "deny"
          }
        }
```

Does rule 100 mean that the dispatcher is not caching any html pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the rule

```
/0100
{
  /glob "*.html"
  /type "deny"
}
```

means that no files with the `.html` extension will be cached. See the [documenatation](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/dispatcher/disp-config.html#Specifying%20the%20Documents%20to%20Cache) for more details.

I'm not sure what that would accomplish on a Publish instance. The only situation where it would seem apt would be if all HTML pages were rendered with user-specific data inline with the static parts (as in, user data rendered in JSP/HTL scripts responsible for displaying whole pages). Not caching HTML pages puts a significant strain on your Publisher farm. If the avoidance of caching dynamic data is the reason for this config, there are better ways to deal with serving user-specific data from AEM, each of which requires a change in your application and deployment architecture ([AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) calls, [Server Side Includes](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html), [Sling Dynamic Inlcudes](https://github.com/apache/sling/tree/trunk/contrib/extensions/sling-dynamic-include), [Edge Side Includes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_Side_Includes), [Templating Engines](https://github.com/Cognifide/knotx/wiki/Architecture), to name a few).

As pointed out in the other answer, this can be a valid rule when the dispatcher is set up in front of an Author environment.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation and additional info

Answer (score 2):

Adding another answer and explanation for the rule from your question:

```
/0100
{
    /glob "*.html"
    /type "deny"
}
```

Yes (as pointed in other answer), it means .html won't be cached. This may sound weird but it's not an uncommon practice when a dispatcher is configured in front of an  AEM author server as described in this [documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher.html#Using%20a%20Dispatcher%20with%20an%20Author%20Server).

The html pages on AEM author are almost session specific so caching them will cause a lot of problems.

In case you are wondering, the dispatcher in front of an AEM author is really effective if you are caching AEM libs and static/non-user specific content.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple explanation:

```
/rules
       {
        # initial blanket deny
          /0000
          {
            /glob "*"
            /type "deny"
          }
          /0100
          {
           /glob "*.html"
           /type "deny"
          }
        }
```

/0000 -- rule will not allow anything to be cached.

if you want something to be cached just mention `allow` as per the below:

```
/rules

      /0100
      {
       /glob "*.html"
       /type "allow"
      }
```